# Error on response.urljoin() - "Cannot mix string and non-string arguments."

Tags: scrapy

I'm getting an error message when using the response.urljoin() function after extracting the href attribute:

`next_page = response.urljoin(href_attribute)`

It says

> Cannot mix string and non-string arguments

Any idea what could be wrong and how to fix that?﻿

Comment: My tip is that `href_attribute` is of type `list` (e.g. was extracted using `extract()` method instead of `extract_first()`), but hard to tell without the rest of code and full trace.

Comment: You're my man of the day :-) God bless

Answer (score 0):

```py
next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
if next_page is not None:
  next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
  yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.